# Hibernate Lazy Loading Not Working as expected

Tags: hibernate

I have user entity with collection of fees. mentioned below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User { ...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Fees> fees = new HashSet<Fees>();
```

while fetching user with id using below mentioned method hibernate fetched fees also

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        return (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }
```

my understanding is hibernate should not fetch fees object but it does so. log prints fees select too.

Hibernate: select fees0_.user_id as user3_8_1_, fees0_.fees_id as fees1_1_, fees0_.fees_id as fees1_5_0_, fees0_.amount as amount5_0_, fees0_.user_id as user3_5_0_ from fees fees0_ where fees0_.user_id=?

Comment: You must have some code, after the call to getUserById(), which causes the collection initialization. Execute the code step by step with your debugger and see when this query is generated by Hibernate.

Comment: you are right, i have overridden tostring method in the user class and was printing fees collection. i think hibernate identified that fees is null so it fetched collection.